# What kind of type-specifier within decl-specifier-seq grammar tree can denote the type-specifier when it's a template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename...T>
void func(T...){
}
```

Consider the above code , it's a case what the standard mentioned:

> There is a syntactic ambiguity when an ellipsis occurs at the end of a parameter-declaration-clause without a preceding comma. In this case, the ellipsis is parsed as part of the **abstract-declarator** if the type of the parameter either names a **template parameter pack** that has not been expanded or contains auto; otherwise, it is parsed as part of the parameter-declaration-clause.

So, the parameter-declaration is the form of the following:
[dcl.fct#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#3)

> parameter-declaration:
>
> > attribute-specifier-seq(opt)   decl-specifier-seq abstract-declarator(opt)

Thereof, the abstract-declarator denotes `...`, However, I couldn't find a type-specifer within `decl-specifier-seq`'s grammar tree can denote `T`.

[dcl.spec#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec#1)

> decl-specifier:
>
> - storage-class-specifier
> - [defining-type-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier)
> - function-specifier
> - friend
> - typedef
> - constexpr
> - inline

> decl-specifier-seq:
>
> > - decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seq (opt)
> > - decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq

Because `T` here is an unexpanded template parameter type. So `T` is not `typedef-name`, because of this:
[temp.param#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#3)

> A type-parameter whose **identifier does not follow an ellipsis** defines its identifier to be a **typedef-name** (if declared without template) or template-name (if declared with template) in the scope of the template declaration. [ Note: A template argument may be a class template or alias template.

So, I wonder what something within the decl-specifier-seq grammar tree  can denote the template parameter pack `T` which has not been expanded? As far as now, I have not found a type-specifier associated with `T`. If I miss anything, Please correct me.

### UPDATE

For this question, I'm digging in the further into [temp.variadic#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#5) section, and I found something that says:

> For the purpose of determining whether a parameter pack satisfies a rule **regarding entities** other than parameter packs, the parameter pack is considered to be the entity that would result from an **instantiation of the pattern in which it appears**.

My reading about this sentence is, the parameter pack is required to satisfy the rule about a parameter-declaration, hence when invoke the function like `func(0,0.1)`, the instantiation of the pattern of the pack expansion are `int,double`, respectively, due to:

[temp.variadic#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#4)

> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below)
>
> > - In a function parameter pack ([dcl.fct]); the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the ellipsis.

So, the results from these instantiations are used to be the type-specifier. It means `int,double` will be the type-specifier for these parameter-declarations of this case `func(0,0.1)`, However it's my reading, I'm not sure it is a relevant rule for this questions.

And it will result in another question, for `template<typename...T> void func(T...);`, the parameter pack is  **not a function parameter pack**, due to this rule:

> A declarator-id or abstract-declarator containing an ellipsis shall only be used in a parameter-declaration. Such a parameter-declaration is a parameter pack. **When it is part of a parameter-declaration-clause**, the parameter pack is a function parameter pack.  [ Note: Otherwise, the parameter-declaration is part of a template-parameter-list and the parameter pack is a **template parameter pack**; see [temp.param].  — end note ]

In my question, the parameter pack is parsed as a part of the abstract-declarator, not the part of a parameter-declaration-clause because the first quote said that. hence, the parameter pack is not considered to be a function parameter pack at all? Now, I think this question has became more complex. I'm looking forward to an answers for this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216941/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-what-kind-of-type-specifier-within-decl-specifi).